# RealmObject serialize in android

Tags: android, serialization, realm

I have a class named Book which extends RealmObject.

And another class like this:

```
class MyNotif {

    int id;
    Book book;

    public void serialize(Bundle bundle) {
        bundle.putSerializable(BUNDLE_KEY, this)
    }
}
```

I get MyNotif object from server and handle it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(myNotif.serialize(new Bundle()));
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Then I get an exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Is that something related to RealmObject serializing? How can I fix that?

Comment: class MyNotif should implements Serializable interface...

Comment: It probably has to do with the fact that `MyNotif` is not `Serializable`, but even then, you should be requerying RealmObjects by their primary key, and not parcelling them.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code like this:

```
class Book extends RealmObject implements Parcelable { ... }
```

or you can external library to handle parsing, check this out.

https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler